# Evitar que imagem pisque quando é usado timer

Tags: delphi, timer, delphi-xe2

Possuo uma imagem de fundo em minha aplicação, porém ela dá a impressão de piscar devido o uso de um `Ttimer` que a aplicação possui.

Tentei alterar o intervalo do `Ttimer` mas o problema persiste.

Alguma dica de como resolver?

Código do timer:

```
procedure TfrmPrincipal.Timer1Timer(Sender: TObject);
begin

if ( TimeToStr(time) < '05:00:00' ) or ( TimeToStr(time) > '24:00:00' ) then Application.Terminate;

    if (timetostr(time) >= '23:50:00') and (timetostr(time) <= '24:00:00') then
    begin
    Timer1.Enabled := false;
    if frmmodulo.qrcaixa_operador.FIELDBYNAME('situacao').AsInteger = 1 then
    begin
    application.messagebox(Pchar('Já são ' + timetostr(time) +
    ' e o Caixa do dia ' + datetostr(frmmodulo.qrcaixa_operador.FIELDBYNAME
    ('data').asdatetime) + #13 + 'Ainda não foi fechado! Verifique!'),
    'Atenção', mb_ok + mb_iconwarning);
    end;
    Timer1.Enabled := true;
    end;

end;
```

Comment: Diz ai qual linguagem você está usando. A Aplicação é Desktop, Web, Mobile? Forneça mais detalhes para nos ajudar a te ajudar.

Comment: Como você esta renderizando ela?

Comment: @QMechanic73 No timer é visto a hora para saber se está próximo das 12h.

Comment: @RenattoMachado é em delphi, aplicação desktop

Comment: @ViníciusGobboA.deOliveira, eu apenas uso um Timage e coloco uma imagem jpeg

Comment: Poste o seu evento `OnTimer`.

Comment: @ViníciusGobboA.deOliveira postado

Comment: Infelizmente não tem nada que aponte para ele. Tem algo causando um `invalidate` no seu form, o que faz com que ele seja renderizado novamente. A única coisa neste método que faria isso é a `MessageBox` quando executada. Você verificou se o seu form esta utilizando double buffering? Habilitando double buffering não removerá o "redesenho" do form, mas provavelmente fará com que a piscada suma.

Comment: Resolvido com isso @ViníciusGobboA.deOliveira. Adicione como resposta para que eu possa marcar como aceita. Muito obrigado

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resposta do Vinícius Gobbo A. de Oliveira:

> Infelizmente não tem nada que aponte para ele. Tem algo causando um
>   invalidate no seu form, o que faz com que ele seja renderizado
>   novamente. A única coisa neste método que faria isso é a MessageBox
>   quando executada. Você verificou se o seu form esta utilizando double
>   buffering? Habilitando double buffering não removerá o "redesenho" do
>   form, mas provavelmente fará com que a piscada suma.